# wpf detects if another software is opened

Tags: c#, wpf, process

I have a WPF program that needs to detect if another software is opened or not. If it is opened, my program will connect to it automatically:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!DataModel.IsConnected)
    {
      connect();
    }
}
```

However, in this way it can only build connection when that software is opened before I run the WPF window. If I want the WPF program can always detect if the software is open - even if the software is opened after I run the WPF window.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, connect() appears to be working.  It just needs to be rewritten to loop until successful.

Comment: @dannymc18 That's exactly what that question answers - how to check if the application is running or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to call the `connect()` method regularly, for example using a timer, or have the other application notify your WPF application at regular intervals.

Here is a basic example that should give you the idea. It calls the `connect()` method once the window has been loaded and if the method returns `false`, it starts a timer that calls the method again every 1.5 seconds until the method returns `true`.

```
System.Timers.Timer _timer;
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!connect())
    {
        //start a timer that calls connect() at regular intervals until it returns true.
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5).TotalMilliseconds);
        _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    }

}

private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (connect())
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: also don't forget the dispatchertimer case you want to do changes on the ui thread

Comment: True, but why would a connect method modify any UI elements?

Comment: someone would want a loading seeking bar or an error message if the connection fails.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question nor the answer.

Comment: Thanks. It is a good way to use timer. Could the parameters in Timer_Elapsed() function be got rid off?

Comment: No, these are part of the signature. You could just ignore them though.